# Haskell: POSIX: SIGCHLD signal handler sometimes isn't called

Tags: haskell, posix

As a learning exercise, I created a small shell in Haskell that supports background jobs and simple stdout redirection. However, there seems to be a race condition in my code that I don't understand. I'm using System.Posix.

```
-- ... imports ...

data Redirection = None
                 | StdOut String
                 deriving (Show)

data Command = Command
  { cProgramName :: String
  , cProgramArgs :: [String]
  , cRedirection :: Redirection
  , cBackground  :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)

data Sync = Sync
  { sMVar        :: MVar ()
  , sRunningJobs :: IORef [ProcessID]
  , sDeadJobs    :: IORef [ProcessID]
  }

withLock :: Sync -> IO () -> IO ()
withLock (Sync mvar _ _) action = do
  putMVar mvar ()
  action
  takeMVar mvar

-- ... parser stuff ...

resolveLine :: Sync -> String -> IO Bool
resolveLine _ "quit" = return False
resolveLine sync line = do
  case P.parse lineParser "" line of
    Left err -> putStrLn (show err)
    Right Nothing -> return ()
    Right (Just (Command prog args redirect bg)) ->
      case Map.lookup prog builtins of
        (Just cmd) -> cmd sync args
        Nothing    -> do
          pid <- forkProcess $ do
            case redirect of
              None -> return ()
              StdOut target -> do
                fd <- openFd target WriteOnly (Just 420) defaultFileFlags { trunc = True }
                void $ dupTo fd stdOutput
                closeFd fd
            executeFile prog True args Nothing
          when bg $
            withLock sync $ modifyIORef (sRunningJobs sync) (pid:)

  return True

runShell :: Sync -> IO ()
runShell sync = do
  wd   <- getCurrentDirectory
  hd   <- getHomeDirectory
  line <- readline $ shortenDirectory hd wd ++ " > "
  case line of
    Nothing     -> putStrLn "" >> return ()
    Just line   -> do
      addHistory line
      -- Reap dead children.
      withLock sync $ readIORef (sDeadJobs sync) >>= mapM_
        (\pid -> do
            getProcessStatus True True pid
            modifyIORef (sDeadJobs sync) (delete pid)
        )
      go <- resolveLine sync line
      when go $ runShell sync

  where shortenDirectory hd wd = if hd `isPrefixOf` wd
                                 then "~" ++ drop (length hd) wd
                                 else wd

handleSigChild :: Sync -> SignalInfo -> IO ()
handleSigChild sync si = do
  withLock sync $ do
    modifyIORef (sRunningJobs sync) (delete pid)
    modifyIORef (sDeadJobs sync) (pid:)
  where
    pid = siginfoPid $ siginfoSpecific si

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mvar <- newEmptyMVar
  rjobs <- newIORef []
  djobs <- newIORef []
  void $ installHandler sigCHLD (CatchInfo $ handleSigChild $ Sync mvar rjobs djobs) Nothing
  runShell $ Sync mvar rjobs djobs
```

Sometimes, when I run `kill` on a background job, the `handleSigChild` function is not called which results in a zombie process, because the child's pid is not added to the shared list of dead processes that will be reaped later. I'm running the `kill` command from within the shell.

Why is the handler executed only once? Is it because the `kill` process itself and the killed process both send the signal almost at the same time? How do I fix it?

Comment: It looks like you diagnosed the problem correctly. It's better to always run wait(2) on all your children in non-blocking mode.